# Meaning for this Stored proc

Tags: t-sql, select, stored-procedures, set, sybase

I have a stored proc but I have no idea what is going on. so anybody could you please explain the stored procedure because based on this I have to modify the other stored procedure.
Here it goes:
**

```
BEGIN
DECLARE
@return_code int
@rows_deleted int outout
@batch_size int 
@purge_before datetime
SET PREFETCH OFF
SELECT @rows_deleted=0,
@return_code=0,
SET rowcount @batch_size
DELETE payee
WHERE cntct_dtm<=@purge_before
SELECT @return_code=@@error, @rows_deleted=@@rowcount
SET rowcount 0
RETURN @return_code
END
```

Comment: Hi, I see you have logged onto to SO recently, and have not yet accepted my answer.  If there was a problem with my answer, please let me know, otheweise please accept my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to take two values as input, an `int` to set the batch size, and `datetime` to set boundaries for the transaction.

1. `rowcount` is set to `batch_size` to limit the number of rows affected in a single pass
2. Delete from the `payee` table where the value of `cntct_dtm` is before the `datetime` value passed into the procedure.
3. Save value `@@error`(most likely 0/1), and `@@rowcount`
4. Change `rowcount` back to normal
5. Return saved value of `@@error`